# pdf as outlook attachment into logic app from azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to add one or several attachments into an automated email stream. The pdfs are coming from a file storage and should be attached as pdf format into the "send an email" workflow. However this does not work.

[image]

```
"Send_an_email_(V2)": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": {
                    "Attachments": [
                        {
                            "ContentBytes": "{@base64(body('Get_file_content'))}",
                            "Name": "test"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Body": "<p>t</p>",
                    "Subject": "t",
                    "To": " "
                },
```

The above gives me the following error: "Cannot convert the literal '{@base64(body('Get_file_content'))}' to the expected type 'Edm.Binary'."

How do I get the pdfs which are setting in the file storage AS A PDF attached into an automated mailing stream please?
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Any reason why you are trying to convert the file content to base64 encoding? There is no need to do this. Just change the name of the file to test.pdf and set the content to "Get_file_content" as shown in the snapshot.

[image]